# Eclipse doesn't recognize GreenMail in a Play project

Tags: eclipse, testing, playframework, mail-server

I want to use GreenMail test suite for mail server testing in my play project in eclipse,but it doesn't recognize GreenMail keyword in my java class(test/default package/GreenMailTest.java)

I put the jars provided by GreenMail package in "myproject/jar/" folder

and here is my dependencies.yml :

```
# Application dependencies
require:
- play
- provided ->greenmail 1.3.1b

repositories:
- provided:
   type:       local
   artifact:   "${application.path}/jar/[module]-[revision].jar"
   contains:
     - provided -> *
```

and I've done these commands:

1. play dependencies myproject
2. play eclipsify myproject

what else to do to make this keyword recognized?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to import this package:

```
com.icegreen.greenmail.util.*
```

and now it's solved